# closing out modal view completely ios

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, exit

I have a messaging system, theres a inbox view and a viewmessage view, if i go back to the inbox im still reciving data from that message, and if i load another conversation between me ad another user its still loading the previous conversation data i had (verified by logging the convo's, and the new one i have open, and its a continuous loop so to say... basically im trying to figure out how to totally close out a view... i seen `dissmissViewController` and used that, but all it does is visually make the view go away... it doesn't truly close it.. whats the method to call to do what im trying to achieve?

These are all modal views, my app uses no navigation views due to the nature of the app

edit: i found some great documentation that im going to look over hopefully i'll get my answer from there.

[Using Delegation to Communicate with Other Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH8-SW9)

Comment: if you are using asynchronous loading of the messages (yourself or with AFNetworking) then the background thread is still loading data even when your view is dismissed.  I think you need to tell the background thread to kill itself when you dismiss the view controller.

Comment: Sounds pretty legit @Gallonallen i'll give it a shot